# Using Telethon and Quart with asyncio yields loop issue "got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon, quart

My telethon bot was working until I added Quart to my project and to main.py

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from bot.telegram_bot import TelegramBot, client
from web.server import create_app
from database.database import setup_database
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def start_telegram_bot(asset_manager):
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]} Script was started.")

    # Start the client
    await client.start()
    print("Client started.")

    # Cache all entities
    await client.get_dialogs()
    print("Cached all entities.")

    bot = TelegramBot()

    # Log that the script was started and is running
    start_script_log_text = f"⏳ | {datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')} | Script started!"
    await bot.send_log_message(start_script_log_text)  # Send log message asynchronously

    # Start the client
    await client.run_until_disconnected()


async def main():
    # Set up the database before starting the Quart app and the main async function
    setup_database()


    # Create the Quart app
    app = create_app()

    # Create a task for the Quart app
    quart_app_task = asyncio.create_task(app.run_task(port=8000))
    # Create a task for the Telegram bot
    bot_task = asyncio.create_task(start_telegram_bot())

    # Start both tasks
    await asyncio.gather(quart_app_task, bot_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

server.py

```
def create_app():
    app = Quart(__name__)
    app.config["DEBUG"] = True  # Enable debug mode

    ...

    return app
```

telegram_bot.py

```
...

client = TelegramClient(session_file_path, API_ID, API_HASH)

bot = Bot(token=BOT_API_TOKEN)

...
```

but this code gets stuck at `await client.start()` and gives me the following error:

`RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-40' coro=<Queue.get() running at c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\queues.py:166> cb=[_release_waiter(<Future pendi...E9FE1E6D0>()]>)() at c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:416]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop`.

If I instead use this approach it is working:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # Get the event loop for the current context
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())  # Run the main coroutine
    finally:
        loop.close()  # Close the loop
```

I read that this approach is soon to be deprecated, and I am using Python 3.9. For this reason I don't want to use this approach.